# Service account delegation with Google workspace - Entity Not found

Tags: c#, google-admin-sdk, google-workspace, google-api-dotnet-client, service-accounts

I am trying to access the Google Directory api as a test this method [domains.list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/domains/list)  using a service account.

If I use the try me on that page logging in with my domain admin email.  It works and I get a response back.  So the method and the customer id i am passing should be working.

I followed the instructions here [Perform Google Workspace Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation)  to create a service account and enable domain wide delegation.

If I check both my workspace account and Google cloud console.  The delegation appears to be configured.  with my domain admin email set as principle.

My code:

```
namespace Daimto.Sample.WorkspaceAdmin
{
    class Program
    {
        private static readonly string[] Scopes = {DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryDomain};
        private static readonly string PathToServiceAccountKeyFile = @"C:\YouTube\workspaceserviceaccount-e4823a933ae3.json";
        private static readonly string CustomerId = "C01lp3chxa";
        private static readonly string workspaceAdmin = "xxx@daimto.com";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            var credential = LoadGoogleCredentails();
            var service = CreateDirectoryService(credential);
            var request = service.Domains.List(CustomerId);
            var result = request.Execute();
            foreach (var domain in result.Domains)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(domain.DomainName);
            }
        }

        private static DirectoryService CreateDirectoryService(GoogleCredential credential)
        {
            return new (new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = "Daimto Testing Workspace with service account"
                }
            );
        }

        private static GoogleCredential LoadGoogleCredentails()
        {
            return GoogleCredential.FromFile(PathToServiceAccountKeyFile)
                .Impersonate(new ImpersonatedCredential.Initializer(workspaceAdmin))
                .CreateScoped(Scopes);
        }
    }
}
```

## error

Running code as it appears above.

> ```
>  "error": {
>     "code": 404,
>     "message": "Requested entity was not found.",
>     "errors": [
>       {
>         "message": "Requested entity was not found.",
>         "domain": "global",
>         "reason": "notFound"
>       }
> ```

Not found implies to me that its not even able to access the domain.

However if I remove the line for impersonation. Then I get this error

> ```
> Not Authorized to access this resource/api [403]
> Errors [
>   Message[Not Authorized to access this resource/api] Location[ - ] Reason[forbidden] Domain[global]
> ]
> ```

This implies to me that without the impersonation it doesn't have access.

So I am confused.  With impersonation it cant find it, without impersonation it can find it but doesn't have access?

The only clue I can find in the documentation is this started note.

[image]

So what exactly do they mean by this `Only users with access to the Admin APIs can access the Admin SDK Directory API` I am admin shouldn't i have access?  Should access be configured if so where?

Answer (score 2):

Ok this required a lot of digging.

There are two methods in the Google .Net client library  [Impersonate()](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/20fe608c5e19d6214edad67c3bc6f343b405a151/Src/Support/Google.Apis.Auth/OAuth2/GoogleCredential.cs#L343) and [CreateWithUser()](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/20fe608c5e19d6214edad67c3bc6f343b405a151/Src/Support/Google.Apis.Auth/OAuth2/GoogleCredential.cs#L285)

> `Impersonate` Allows this credential to impersonate the  ImpersonatedCredential.Initializer.TargetPrincipal. Only ServiceAccountCredentialand UserCredential support impersonation, so this method will throw <see InvalidOperationException if this credential's
> UnderlyingCredential is not of one of those supported types.

while

> `CreateWithUser` If the credential supports Domain Wide Delegation, this method creates a copy of the credential with the specified user. Otherwise, it throws <see InvalidOperationException. At the moment only ServiceAccountCredential supports Domain Wide Delegation.

So the key here is are you trying to **delegate** to a user or **impersonate** a user. There is a difference.

So by using CreateWithUser it now works.

```
 private static GoogleCredential LoadGoogleCredentails()
        {
            return GoogleCredential.FromFile(PathToServiceAccountKeyFile)
                .CreateScoped(Scopes)
                .CreateWithUser(workspaceAdmin);
        }
```